# Crash when using $q on an angularjs and parse app

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am learning how to use $q for asynchronous code. I have not found any information about how to use this for a function outside of the controller function.  I have the code below and it crashes right after the $q.defer() line and I don't know why.

```
function playerNames($q) {

Parse.$ = jQuery;

Parse.initialize("mykey", "mykey");

var namesdfd = $q.defer();
.
.
.
};

app.controller('NameController', ['$scope', function($scope, $q) {scope.names = playerNames($q)}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to inject `$q` dependency inside your controller Dependency array. Application was getting crashed because you have `$q` which is `undefined` & `undefined`'s `.defer()` throwing an error.

**Code**

```
app.controller('NameController', ['$scope', '$q', //<--you need to inject it here.
  function($scope, $q) {
   scope.names = playerNames($q)
  }
]);
```